# in Python, is there a way to break a wrapping, centered text prhase so that there is not a single word left hanging under a long string?

Tags: python

in Python, is there a way to break a wrapping, centered text prhase so that there is not a single word left hanging under a long string?

Example, assuming this is centered:

**West Dakota Department of Fish and

```
        Game**
```

The word "Game" is short, and the string above is long.  Does not look good as a header for a website. Would like a method to instead display the following:

**West Dakota Department

of Fish and Game**

Maybe using javascript?

Comment: How are you displaying this to begin with to believe that JavaScript would be a viable option here?

Comment: The string is the name of an organization, from a table.  Cannot  predict how long, how many words will be in an organization's title.  It's displayed using a Web2py controller in a view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a couple of things, you could get fancy and parse the length of the longest sub-string as well rather than specifying the format width (eg. ^20) in the centering portion of the expression

```
>>> import textwrap
>>> a = "West Dakota Department of Fish and Game"
>>> wdth = int(len(a)/2)
>>> args = textwrap.wrap(a, wdth)
>>> print(("{!s:^20}\n"*len(args)).format(*args))
    West Dakota     
 Department of Fish 
      and Game
```

Comment: @AlexGlaros perhaps you could mark the answer correct so that resolution has been noted.